# Media query not applying for desired screen size

Tags: css, media-queries

I am creating a mobile design for certain mobile screens, so I want to apply my styles for screens that are 275px wide up to 812. Currently for some reason the styles defined for this media query get applied from 303 to 812 width but bellow that they don't have any effect. Is my media query wrong for what I am trying to achieve? Here is how it looks:

```
@media screen and (min-width:275px) and (max-width:812px) {}
```

and here is my view port line in the html:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good; it's working just fine on here. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but the media query won't work below a specified minimum width (or below 275px in this case). It will be bound to the constraints you have set.

```css
@media screen and (min-width:275px) and (max-width:812px) {
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Again, if you want the styles to work **below** 275px, you'll have to lower/remove the `min-width` constraint. As I've mentioned, it's working just fine on here so there may be something wrong with your browser's viewport accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is to have a particular style applied from 275px to 812px of screen width:

```
@media screen and (min-width:275px) and (max-width:812px){
```

this is correct, i've tested it in chrome dev tools and it seems fine,
with that code it correctly apply the styles from 275px until 812px.

maybe the problem is in other media queries